# Product of two independent poisson variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have two independent poisson variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $X_1 ∼ \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 ∼ \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2)$. What will be the probability distribution of $X_1 \times X_2$? Is it some standard distribution?

I am particularly interested in the mean value of the distribution.

Additional question: If I have chain of $N$ poisson variables, can we say anything about mean value of the multiplication of these variables?

I could not find any online resource discussing this.

Comment: Not a standard distribution. But independence guarantees that the mean of the product is the product $\lambda_1\lambda_2$ of the means.

Comment: Can you provide the reference for that? That would be helpful.

Comment: [Yes I can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Expectation_and_covariance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $X_1,X_2$ are independent you get:

$$E[X_1X_2]=E[X_1]E[X_2]=\lambda_1\lambda_2$$

just using the definition of independence! I would recommend to check the definition.

Comment: Ah! Silly me. I was going through [Product distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution). Thanks